# Linking actions to buttons on a modal/popover segue (swift 2 Xcode 7)

Tags: xcode, swift, button, segue

I'm sure I'm asking a simple question but I've only just started coding... so take pity on me!
I'm trying to figure out how to connect buttons (actions) to the `viewController.swift` from a modal/popover segue (I think the solution is the class but whenever I change it I get an error).

Eg.

In the storyboard, on the `viewController` interface, I have a button for sharing files. When I click it, a popover segue appears with two buttons on it, one for Fb one for Twitter, but I can't connect any actions from them to the `viewController.swift`

In another project I made a Google+ login and connected it to a modal segue but I couldn't make that work either.

Is segue the wrong thing to use?

Thanks for your help!

Marie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question would be easier to answer if you'd provide the actual error you're getting when you try to change the class.

It *sounds* like you're trying to connect the popover's buttons to actions in the *presenting* view controller (that is, the view controller that presented the popover), rather than the view controller of the popover itself. If that's the case, then that's the problem. You can only connect your buttons directly to actions available in the current scene.

This means you need a custom class for the presenting view controller (the one with the button that segues to the popover controller) and one for your popover. Set each scene view controller's classes to the appropriate custom classes you created (which must be a subclass of NSViewController or one of *its* subclasses or you won't be able to set the class name in IB) and you should be able to drag connections.